# Adding arbitrary objects in the OpenFire Session

Tags: openfire

We have an existing OAuth2 based website.  Our plan is to use a web based (XMPP over websockets) chat system.
now this chat system will be available once the user logs in.  What we actually do not want is to login twice, once for the web site and once for the chat system.
So I figured how to trick it with my own auth provider and a custom username/password.
So basically the question is how do I have an object that I want to travel along with the user chat session so that I can provide out of band processing.
Does the session management allow this?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar use-case, there I need to persist and store various pieces of information about a user, in Openfire, so that external calls and look-ups are not necessary during later, custom logic in an Openfire plugin. It is possible to add any number of custom properties to an openfire user, via REST, or other APIs.

Then, those custom properties can be retrieved as needed, without external calls.

[create user api](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-user)

Then, if using Internal APIs,  you get

1. Get the session's username or address (JID)
2. call UserManager's [getUser](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/4e755241b5213fd2c6cf72102d30a16ef8b7fa69/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/user/UserManager.java#L259) on the username or JID to get the User object
3. call User's [getPropertyValue](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/4e755241b5213fd2c6cf72102d30a16ef8b7fa69/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/user/User.java#L83) to get a specific property or [getProperties](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/4e755241b5213fd2c6cf72102d30a16ef8b7fa69/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/user/User.java#L359) to retrieve all custom user properties

Comment: So, this looks like an external api to OF server call.  How do I attach these properties to the actual session?  I wasn't clearly seeing that.  Thanks

Comment: How are you accessing the session? If not REST API, are you using Openfire internal APIs, Smack? etc Need more info to help you better.

Comment: it would be entirely an internal API.  The problem was that I could not find one.  Thanks